# C socket: recv jams the program if used twice

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I'm trying to implement C code on a UNIX platform which sends all files data to the client, and uploading a file from the client to the server.

The first part is working but for the second part I've encountered an issue.
After some debugging I've found out that the server side jams the client when I'm using recv the second time in the code [I've marked it for your convenience].

I've tried to look up on guides or what I'm doing wrong but I couldn't find the issue for what causing the program to get stuck.

*For de-bugging purposes I'm now trying to send an int from client to the server*

server side

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define PORT 0x0da2
#define IP_ADDR 0x7f000001
#define QUEUE_LEN 20

int main(void)
{
    //char directory[1024];
    //chdir("server");
    //getcwd(directory, sizeof(directory));
    //printf("%s",directory);
    DIR* directory;
    struct dirent* ent;
    int fd;
    char buffer[1000] = {0};
    char convert[100] = {0};
    size_t array_size = 0;
    struct stat fileStat;
    if ((directory = opendir ("server")) == NULL) 
    {
            perror ("Cannot open .");
            return 1;
        }

    while ((ent = readdir(directory)) != NULL) 
    {

        if (!( !strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(ent->d_name, "..")) )
        {
            fd = openat(dirfd(directory), ent->d_name, 0);

            if (fd == -1)
            {
                perror ("Can't get stats.");
                return 1;
                }   

            if(fstat(fd, &fileStat)== -1)
            {
                perror ("Can't get stats.");
                return 1;
                }
            strcat(buffer,ent->d_name);
            sprintf(convert,"%lld", (long long) fileStat.st_size);
            strcat(buffer, " ");
            strcat(buffer,convert);
            strcat(buffer,"\n");

        }
        }

    int listenS = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (listenS < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in s = {0};
    s.sin_family = AF_INET;
    s.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    s.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(IP_ADDR);

    if (bind(listenS, (struct sockaddr*)&s, sizeof(s)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind");
        return 1;
    }

    if (listen(listenS, QUEUE_LEN) < 0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in clientIn;
    int clientInSize = sizeof clientIn;

    while (1)
    {
        int newfd = accept(listenS, (struct sockaddr*)&clientIn, (socklen_t*)&clientInSize);

        if (newfd < 0)
        {
            perror("accept");
            return 1;
        }

        if (send(newfd, &buffer, strlen(buffer), 0) < 0)
        {
            perror("send");
            return 1;
        }

        char namebuff[100] = {0};
        char sizebuff[256] = {0};
        //int size;
        ssize_t nrecv;
        int error = 0;
        int fsize;
        //int dataleft;

        if ((nrecv = recv(newfd, &namebuff, sizeof(namebuff), 0)) < 0)
        {
        perror("recv");
        return 1;
        }

        if((strstr(buffer,namebuff) != NULL))
        {
                error = -1;

                if (send(newfd, &error, sizeof(int), 0) < 0)
                {
                    perror("send");
                    return 1;
                }

        }

        /*if ((nrecv = recv(newfd, &fsize, sizeof(int), 0)) < 0) //this line is what jams the program
            {
            perror("recv");
            return 1;
            }*/

        if(error != -1) // 
        {

            if ((nrecv = recv(newfd, &sizebuff, sizeof(sizebuff), 0)) < 0)
            {
            perror("recv");
            return 1;
            }

        fsize = atoi(sizebuff);
        }


        printf("%s\n",namebuff);
        printf("%d\n",fsize);
        close(newfd);
    }
    close(listenS);

    return 0;
}
```

client side

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define PORT 0x0da2
#define IP_ADDR 0x7f000001
int ctoi(char c) {

    return c-'0';

}


int main(void)
{
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    ssize_t nrecv;
    struct sockaddr_in s = {0};
    s.sin_family = AF_INET;
    s.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    s.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(IP_ADDR);

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&s, sizeof(s)) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Successfully connected.\n");
    char buffer[1000] = {0};

    if ((nrecv = recv(sock, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("recv");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("./client list-files\n%s\n", buffer); //nrcev gives the size of the data is recived

    int fd;
    //int i;
    //ssize_t nwrite, nread;
    char sizebuff[256];
    struct stat file_stat;
    int numcheck = 0;
    //char buffer2[4096];
    char namebuff[100] = "coolfile.txt";
    fd=open("coolfile.txt",O_RDONLY);

    if (send(sock, &namebuff, strlen(namebuff), 0) < 0)
        {
            perror("send");
            return 1;
        }

    /*if ((nrecv = recv(sock, &numcheck, sizeof(int), 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("recv");
        return 1;
    }*/

    if (numcheck == -1)
    {
        printf("file already exists in the server\n");
        return 1;
    }

        if (fstat(fd, &file_stat) < 0)
            {
            printf("error");

                    return 1;
            }

        sprintf(sizebuff, "%ld", file_stat.st_size);
        //printf("%s\n",sizebuff);
        /*int number = 5;

        if(send(sock, &number, sizeof(int), 0) < 0)
            {
                    printf("error");

                    return 1;
            }*/


        if(send(sock, &sizebuff, strlen(sizebuff), 0) < 0);
            {
                    printf("error");

                    return 1;
            }
        /*
        nread = read(fd, buffer2, 4096);

        for (i = 0; i < nread; i += nwrite)
        {
            nwrite = write(sock, buffer2 + i, nread - i);
        }

    } while (nread != 0);*/
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: regarding the posted code for the client:  running it through a compiler ( `gcc` with the options: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Werror -pedantic -std=gnu11` ) results in lots of messages from the compiler, several of which are critical.  Please fix your code.  Similar conditions exist for the posted server code.

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.

Comment: when calling any C library functions, always check for errors, do not assume the operation was successful

Comment: I see, thanks for letting me know about that, didn't knew there's such an option.

I'll go over my code and edit it in a way it's more readeble, thanks.

Comment: Please code using the correct variable typing.  For instance the function: `recv()` returns a `ssize_t`, not an`int`

Comment: [gcc options](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_the_GNU_Compiler_Collection/invoking-gcc.html)

Comment: Thanks, the only warnings I'll let through right now is the unused variables, as I hide some parts of the code in purpose to solve the issue.

Comment: regarding: `char buffer[1000] = {0};` and the `while()` loop that is appending all the sub directory file names into that buffer,  This is very likely to overrun that buffer, resulting in undefined behavior.  Suggest, initialize the buffer as a pointer to char, containing NULL, then use `realloc()` to expand that buffer before each file name is added.

Comment: regarding: ``fstat(fd, &fileStat);
    while ((ent = readdir(directory)) != NULL) `  What is this specific call to `fstad()` for?  The results of this call are never used

Comment: regarding: `if (send(newfd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) < 0)`  Suggest using `strlen()` rather than `sizeof`

Comment: regarding, in the client: `char buffer[1000];
    if ((nrecv = recv(sock, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)) < 0)` and my above comment, suggest sending the first message containing only the strlen() of the buffer so the client can prepare an adequate length receiving area

Comment: Maybe that's what causing the issue, I'll try to fix that like you said and I'll tell if it worked,
about fstas call there, it was a leftover code and I haven't noticed that.

about strlen I'll try that either.

Comment: in the client, regarding: `fd=open("coolfile.txt",O_RDONLY);`  what happens if the call to `open()` fails?  Always check the error status of calls to C library functiosn

Comment: regarding: ` if (send(sock, &namebuff, sizeof(namebuff), 0) < 0)`  as in the prior comment, only send the actual data (I.E. use `strlen()` rather than `sizeof` so the server is not receiving trash (that might be mistaken for a continuation of the file name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184566/discussion-between-play38-and-user3629249).

Comment: in the server, regarding: `if((strstr(buffer,namebuff) != NULL))`  before this statement, insert a statement to NUL terminate the array of characters in `namebuff`  otherwise the statement will (most likely) fail

Comment: You'll definitely run into issues because TCP is stream oriented .There's no guarantee that a single `send()` on one side of a connection is completely received in a single `recv()` on the other side. In other words, one side could `send()` a 1K buffer and the other side could (in theory) `recv()` one byte at at time, regardless of the buffer size passed into the `recv()` API.

Comment: _Side note:_ In the server, before you do the `bind`, you may have to do: `int enable = 1; setsockopt(listenS, SOL_SOCKET, (SO_REUSEPORT | SO_REUSEADDR), &enable, sizeof(enable));` Otherwise, you may get a "socket already in use" error

Comment: I think that's where the issue with my code, as you said @keithmo I've noticed that sometimes the client receives the data from the first call of recv and sometimes at the second call of recv, I bet it's mainly because of that.